# Ordering Cloud Server by SoftLayer API

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to order SoftLayer's virtual server by python API.

by following API call=>

```
client['Product_Package'].getAllObjects(mask='id, name')
```

I found the pkg id for virtual server is 46.

Also, I found the prices id by following API call=>

```
client['Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=46, mask='id, itemId, recurringFee, hourlyRecurringFee, item.description, item.keyName, categories.id')`
```

And ordering code is following=>

```
order = {
    'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest',
    'quantity': 1,
    'virtualGuests': [
        {'hostname': 'test-template', 'domain': 'example.com'}
    ],
    'location': 449604,  # Tokyo
    'packageId': 46,  # CCI Package
    'prices': [
        {'id':34183},  # 1000 GB Bandwidth
        {'id':112483},  # 1 x 2.0 GHz Core
        {'id':32578},  # 25 GB (SAN)
        {'id':27023},  # Host Ping Monitoring
        {'id':32500},  # Email and Ticket Notifications
        {'id':31985},  # CentOS 5 - Minimal Install (32 bit)
        {'id':27052},  # 10 Mbps Private Networks
        {'id':34807},  # 1 IP Address
        {'id':112985},  # 1 GB RAM
        {'id':23070},  # Reboot / Remote Console
        {'id':32627},  # Automated Notification Response
        {'id':35310},  # Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reporting
        {'id':33483},  # Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account
    ],
    'imageTemplateId': templateId
}
client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
```

However, there was following alert=>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ordervsByimg.py", line 45, in <module>
    result = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].verifyOrder(order)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 392, in call_handler
    return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 360, in call
    return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 263, in call
    return self.transport(request)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 195, in __call__
    raise _ex(ex.faultCode, ex.faultString)
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): The price for 1 x 2.0 GHz Core (#112483) is not valid for location tok02.
```

Could you please help me for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that according the location that you picked out you need to pick the prices for that location as well.

The prices have a property called "locationGroup" this property contains the information about in what locations the price will work, also in order to avoid to have to pick everytime a particular price for a particular location softlayer have standard prices these prices work for any location, in order to get those prices you need to look for the prices whose "locationGroupId" is null.

Take a look at this documentation about this:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you